# MySQL, getting all top users

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named `items` which has 3 columns : `id, user_id, item_name`.
I want to select and show all users that have most submitted items in that table.

For instance :

```
User-1 has 3 items, 
User-2 has 8 items, 
User-3 has 5 items, 
User-4 has 8 items, and 
User-5 has 8 items too.
```

Based on what I need, the query should be outputting User-2, User-4 and User-5.

My knowledge of MySQL is not thorough unfortunately and I can't get this done by myself.

Your help is much appreciated.

**EDIT #1 :**

Here's the query that I tried and didn't output my desired result :

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS total_count
     , user_id 
  FROM ".DB_PREFIX."items 
 GROUP 
    BY user_id
```

It shows all users and their total number of items submitted. As I mentioned earlier, I need all top users.

Comment: wasn't there a similar question like this a day or so ago? I remember this.

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner : I found some topic similar to my question, but they either needed only the top record to be shown (which could be done by LIMIT), or they needed all records just with some ordering. Maybe there's also an exact question out there like mine, and my search wasn't just thorough ...

Comment: Your question is both unclear and too broad. Can you post something that you tried and it may have failed you? That way it would have at least shown some effort on your part and we can see if you made an error somewhere. Remember, we're always glad to help those who first help themselves ;-)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner : Sure thing. Well the table is that simple let's say. There are some other columns there. But they are irrelevant to my query. Here's the query that I tried and didn't output my desired result : `SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS total_count, user_id FROM ".DB_PREFIX."items GROUP BY user_id` It shows all users and their total number of items submitted.

Comment: update your post instead https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48610105/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E.g.:

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM   
     ( SELECT user_id
            , COUNT(*) total 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY user_id
     ) a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT COUNT(*) total 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY user_id 
        ORDER 
           BY total DESC 
        LIMIT 1
     ) b 
    ON b.total = a.total;
```